# Applying a Rust attribute to more than one line

Tags: rust, attributes, conditional-compilation

To the best of my understanding of [the Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html), attributes are applied only to the line directly following an attribute. So, if I want to [conditionally compile](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute) a line I can do this:

```
#[cfg(target_family = "unix")]
use termion::{color, style};
```

What happens when I want to conditionally compile two lines?

```
#[cfg(target_family = "unix")]
use termion::{color, style};
#[cfg(target_family = "unix")]
use termion::screen::*;
```

Is there a cleaner way for doing this?

Comment: Well, in this case, you can merge those imports into to one line: `use termion::{coloe, style, screen::*}`. But it may not answer your Q in general.

Comment: @edwardw, true, I'm looking for a more general answer

Comment: Side note: there'a at least [one crate](https://github.com/crossterm-rs/crossterm/) tackling the problem of cross-platform use of the terminal.

Comment: @DenysSéguret thanks I wasn't aware of it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no general grouping answer to my knowledge but there are specific solutions.

Most often, you can just use a block:

```
#[cfg(target_family = "unix")]
{
    // some code
}
```

`use` statements can always be grouped together, even when there's no common root:

```
#[cfg(target_family = "unix")]
use {
    termion::{color, style},
    std::io,
};
```

> attributes are applied only to the line directly following an attribute

Not really. They're applied to the following "thing". There's a list of supported "things" [in the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html). It's not all what you'd probably want (it's not an `if` expression for example) but there's already a lot of covered ground.

Answer (score 0):

For people that come to this page seeking a general answer to "Applying a Rust attribute to more than one line", and not just module related attributes; a more general idea that could be used to apply an attribute to all items in a pseudo block, without creating a compile-time scoping problem, would be the macro, `apply_attrib` below.

```rust
// Apply the same attribute to all items in the block, but don't compile it as 
// an actual block.
macro_rules! apply_attr {
    { #!$attr:tt $($it:item)* } => {
        $(
            #$attr
            $it
        )*
    }
}

apply_attrib! {
    #![allow(non_camel_case_types)]

    type c_ptr_hook = c_void;

    type c_ptr_list = c_void;

    #[allow(dead_code)]
    type c_ptr_context = c_void;

    // Many more `item`s...
}

// Declaration is accessible outside the pseudo block.
fn foo(p: *const c_ptr_hook) {
    // ...
}
```

An `item` in the rules applies to the type declarations and many other things; [see the reference on item here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items.html). And here's the [reference on macro metavariables](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#metavariables).

This example can handle applying one attribute to all items in the pseudo block. Which solved my needs for a project, but if anyone has any suggestions that would make it so more than one attribute could be applied, please leave me a comment.